# Building an RPM from a 3rd Party Binary Package

Tags: linux, rpm, puppet

We are switching over to using puppet for configuration management of our Linux based systems.  We have several 3rd party packages which contain custom binary installers (think JDK) and are using RPM to build them into local-only non-distributed packages.  One troublesome package has an install process which requires the following:
a) Untar binary package into *install* directory X.
b) Run "installer" which prompts for license acceptance and then *modifies/embeds the install directory path into many subsequent scripts in the install directory*.

I'm having problems defining a spec file to install this package.  For starters, in %install I handle step a and then run the installer from step b.  This installs the package into $RPM_BUILD_ROOT as expected.  However the package scripts are all embedded with $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/ rather than just  which breaks the scripts embedded with the install directory.  Is there a way to run this installer as if it were in a chroot environment or some other alternative here?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: [mach](http://www.howtoforge.com/building-rpm-packages-in-a-chroot-environment-using-mach) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, thanks mach looks like a good prospect.  We're limited to standard CentOs yum repositories and I didn't see it there, but I can probably get around this.  I'd give you props but my reputation forbids it ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Fedora (and I suspect also RHEL/CentOS) there is [mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock) for exactly the type of task you describe. It is for building packages, but the "populate the chroot" part should be easy to (mis)use to create the environment you need.